# C++ calling static function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, static, function-pointers

I would like to forward a callback to a function pointer. So I declare a static (int*) m_pointer1, as well as a method void RegisterCallback1( (int*)fct)

in class1.h:

```
public:
   int RegisterCallback1( int (*fct) );
private:
   static int (*m_Callback1);
```

in class1.cpp:

```
int class1::RegisterCallback1( int (*fct) )
{
    m_Callback1= fct;
}
```

then, I want to forward the callback to the function pointer:

```
void class1::Callback1()
{
   (*m_Callback1)();
}
```

But I get a compiler error "Expression must have (pointer-to)- function type
I have followed tutorial and read about function pointers and they seem to do it this way without any problems. Any ideas why?

EDIT:
So, I declare (int*)(void)m_Callback1 -Visual Studio requires a void there...-
Then how do I call the registerCallback function with the argument?

```
class1.RegisterCallBack1(  ??? - class2::callback -??? );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't declared a function pointer, you've declared a normal data pointer. You are missing () at the end of the declaration.

Comment: Thats great and all, but then how do I call the registerCallback1 function with an argument?
class1.RegisterCallBack1(  ??? - class2::callback -??? );

Comment: @David : Assuming `class2::callback` is `static`, `c1.RegisterCallBack1(&class2::callback)`.

Comment: this gives out another error: argumen of type void(__stdcall *)() is not compatible with parameter of type void(*)(). If I add __stdcall to function pointer decleration, I get linking errors, saying that m_callback1() cannot be found in class1 (not class2)

Answer (score 7):

`static int (*m_Callback1)` does not declate a function pointer, just a pointer to int: you forgot about the parameter list. You meant:

```
static int (*m_Callback1)();
```

and

```
int RegisterCallback1( int (*fct)() );
```

Comment: Thats great, but then how to I pass it to RegisterCallback1? I tried something like class1.RegisterCallback1( (int*) class2::callback ); and many combinations, they all seems to give me an error? Always something with argument of type int* incompatible with (int*)()

Answer (score 1):

You can try to limit the missing () errors pointed out by Oli and Dave by using a typedef for the callback function's signature: `typedef int (*)() CallBack;` This would at least have the merit of letting you think once about the precise number of brackets rather than at every point in your code where you use such a function.